# Export to Excel as multiple sheets in a file (parallel multiple threads)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

ASP.NET 3.5

- I am trying to export the customer company details present inside
  GridView (**each row has one Company Customer Record**, contains all details
  or Customer Object), along with the details some Charts (based on
  values) also needs to be exported to Excel in the fixed format [as
  given in the SRS Requirement].

  - I am showing the customer details in GridView with paging option. ASP
    Page has detailed in GridView and a **Export Button** at its corner,
    once it's clicked I need to get the downloaded file (one Excel file)
    containing sheets, **each sheet has one customer report which also has
    charts and Date-Timings when it's printed.**

    1. I tried to export direct from GridView but it's just showing the GridView itself (I don't need this).
    2. I tried to export by taking an Excel file and filling cell by cell and creating new sheets but it's not possible in GoDaddy Hosted Server since some .dll or MS Office is not installed on server machine.

**How to export to Excel sheets**?

[image]

Comment: I can't alter the clients requirements. Help Me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EasyXLS](http://www.easyxls.com) Excel library to export data to Excel. Start with [this page](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/create-excel-file.html) to see code samples on how to add the sheets and export data to gridview. You will also find code samples about charts.

To export the gridview to each sheet, you need to adjust the sample code for gridview like this:

```
((ExcelWorksheet)xls.easy_getSheetAt(sheet)).easy_insertDataSet(dataSet, 
                                                    xlsAutoFormat, true)
```